# SQL Sum with conditions in two columns

Tags: sql, vb.net, sum

I'm very new to SQL and VB.NET. I have an existing table called `STOCK` with the columns shown here, and I want to sum buy and sell to display current quantity.

Existing table:

| ID | Date | BUY | SELL | Current quantity |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 01/01/22 | 88 | 0 |  |
| 2 | 03/01/22 | 22 | 0 |  |
| 94669 | 05/02/22 | 0 | 30 |  |

I want to display in Current quantity like this

```
(the current quantity amount in the row above + BUY - SELL)
```

I add result in `Current` quantity manually, but I want to do this in automatic way it is possible in SQL code

| ID | Date | BUY | SELL | Current quantity |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 01/01/22 | 88 | 0 | 88 |
| 2 | 03/01/22 | 22 | 0 | 110 |
| 3 | 05/02/22 | 0 | 30 | 80 |

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
select a.*,
     sum(net_sell) over (order by Curr_date ) as Current_quantity 
from 
(select s.*, 
        buy-sell as net_sell 
from stock s) a ;
```

Dbfiddle link :  https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=196a41a578d1e699ccaa3e878e261019

Comment: This is Work Perfect but how can i Filter buy ID example to get result only from rows what have ID 1.